# SWIG for Go - how do I set include pathes for c++ headers

Tags: c++, swig, go-build

I am trying to use a C++ library in a Go project with the help of SWIG.  I have added a .swigcxx file with the necessary headers into my GO project directory, but they are not found by Go-GCC compiler as they are placed in other directories. I get error like

```golang
# ./xwrapper
x.swigcxx(3) : Error: Unable to find Stream.h
```

Ho do I tell "go build" where swig should look for the headers?  SWIG itself has an "-I" command line option, but how do I pass it to "swig for go"?

Thank you very much in advance,

Yuliana